draw a Rectangular cuboid ABCDEFGH
I need draw a Rectangular cuboid so I have this code
  \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
  \usepackage{tikz}

  \tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=1.5pt}}

  \begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
    \draw  (206,177.74) -- (253.94,129.8) -- (372.8,129.8)
    -- (372.8,241.66) -- (324.86,289.6) -- (206,289.6) -- cycle ;
    \draw  (372.8,129.8) -- (324.86,177.74) -- (206,177.74) ;
    \draw  (324.86,177.74) -- (324.86,289.6) ;
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


But I need draw  Rectangular cuboid like this photo

So I need some help to complete.

Thanks.

We actually have fantastic resources for cubes and cuboids: simple ones, annotated ones, rotated ones, stacked ones, ones which are shaded and ones which are plain, ones which are misty and mysterious, ones which shine and ones which don't .... Note that one of the answers to the question I've linked is actually a list of links to answers to other questions on drawing cuboids and cubes. Once you have your chosen cuboid, it should be simple to add the plane as you'll have the four coordinates you need already, but please ask a followup question if you get stuck at that point.

To get started with tikz, you have excellent tutorials here https://tikz.dev/
Start with Tutorial: A Picture for Karl’s Students.

@cfr I think that the example that the OP is looking for is not in any of the posts in the duplicate link, since they have some challenging things such as drawing the inclined plane but in a way that you can draw on it just like you do with canvas is plane xy or similar. Well, it's the price of not asking good questions to get good answers.

@JLeonV. You might be right. I admit that I failed to get that from the squiggle. But it would be better, in that case, to set up the cube and plane and ask how to draw on it. Or am I still misunderstanding?
